# Can Angular $resource.get handle both array and non-array for GET?

Tags: angularjs

There are two ways I can GET a REST resource by ID:

```
GET /users/1
GET /users/1,2
```

The first returns a single object like `{id:1,name:"John"}` while the second returns an array like `[{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"Jill"}]`.

Please, no arguments about whether or not this is legit REST; just accept that a service has this and I need to work with it.

angular's $resource actually intelligently handles it from the *request* side:

```
User.get({users:['1','2']})
```

transforms into

```
GET /users/1,2
```

But it doesn't handle the response well. It expects a single object. If I change the definition to `isArray:true`, then it fails on a single request `GET /users/1`

How do I get it to intelligently handle both?

EDIT: I did some weird hacking to get it to work, but would prefer a native method:

```
    factory('Resource',['$resource','_',function ($resource,_) {
    return function(url,params,methods){
        var defaults = {
            getSingle: {method: 'get', isArray:false},
            getMultiple: {method: 'get', isArray:true}
        }, resource = $resource(url,params,angular.extend(defaults,methods)), urlParams = {};
  _.each(url.split(/\W/), function(param){
    if (param && (new RegExp("(^|[^\\\\]):" + param + "\\W").test(url))) {
      urlParams[param] = true;
    }
  });

        // do not override if they did
        if (!(methods||{}).get) {
            resource.get = function (params,success,error) {
                // look for multiples
                var isMultiple = false;
                _.each(params,function (val,key) {
                    if (key && urlParams[key] && angular.isArray(val)) {
                        isMultiple = true;
                        return(false);
                    }
                });
                return this[isMultiple?"getMultiple":"getSingle"](params,success,error);
            };
        }
        return(resource);
    };
}]).
```

Answer (score 4):

The normal convention is to create a `Resource.get()` method for single objects, and a `Resource.query()` method for arrays of them.

Comment: Well, query is for general query by different params. This is definitely a `get` but for multiple... and even $resource knows what to do on the *request* side, because it converts it to a comma-separated list. You saying I will need `Resource.getMultiple()` or similar?

Comment: Yeah, I would try that.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with the [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) when trying to do a PUT request to a post. Currently that API returns an object representing the post if everything went okay, but if there is an error (eg the authorization credentials don't match) then it returns an array of errors. So I was getting the error `Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array`.

I managed to find a solution by using the transformResponse property on my custom action object. I define a function which inspects the response and then if it is an array, it converts the array into an object. This seems to work okay, and seems a bit less complex than the solution you posted in your update:

```
var wpPost = $resource(PATH_TO_WORDPRESS_API + 'posts/:id', {},
        {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {id: '@id'},
                transformResponse: function(data) {
                    var response = angular.fromJson(data);

                    if (response.length) {
                        // the response is an array, so convert it into an object
                        var object = {};
                        for( var i = 0; i < response.length; i ++) {
                            object[i] = response[i];
                        }
                        return object;
                    } else {
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: this one should be the selected anwser so simple as change the reponse in the transformReponse method but ill sugest you change the if statement to if (response instanceof Array) it will be more accurate