# AngularJS : $resource, response Object or Array

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I get response array or object, how to setup $resource query for same ?

```
 var getUser = $resource(':controller/:action', {
        controller: 'Users',
        action: 'getUser'
    }, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true  // How to set true or False
        }
    });
```

It works when i receive response as array, but doesn't work when i get response as object.

Comment: What if you include after `isArray: true` this => `transformResponse: function(data) { return angular.fromJson(data); }`? By the way, it was already answered in many topics, here is one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071105/can-angular-resource-get-handle-both-array-and-non-array-for-get

Comment: @developer033 : thanks, transformResponse worked.